# How to re-purpose existing instances of Redis and RabbitMQ with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

After successfully developing an application with multiple ServiceStack services, we are moving to other testing environments, lots of them due to us running a SAAS model (aka multi-tenant). I'd like to reuse some of the base infrastructure services, primarily Redis and RabbitMQ across a few of these environments.

We're using the IAppSetting interface to pull our configuration from multiple sources into one cohesive settings object at run-time, which is then filtered tier. Since tier drives the configuration per environment it made sense to use Tier to prefix any RabbitMQ messages queues, and prefix any generated cache keys that will be used by Redis, thus providing collision protection per environment.

Below is an example:

RabbitMQ => "Some MQ method here"  => "**mq:qa1.Outbound.inq**"

Redis => "Some Redis method here"  => "**urn:qa1.somePoco:123**"

Here is an example configuration and the various enviroments

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Tier" value="qa1" />
    <!--<add key="Tier" value="dev" />-->
    <!--<add key="Tier" value="tst" />-->
    <!--<add key="Tier" value="stg" />-->
    <!--<add key="Tier" value="prod" />-->
</appSettings>
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples on how to modify Queue Names are in [MqNameTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Server.Tests/Messaging/MqNameTests.cs), e.g:

```
QueueNames.SetQueuePrefix("site1.");
```

Will add a prefix on QueueNames, e.g:

```
site1.mq:TestPrefix.inq
```

Otherwise you can use `QueueNames.ResolveQueueNameFn` to have complete control over the MQ name, e.g:

```
QueueNames.ResolveQueueNameFn = (typeName, suffix) =>
    "SITE.{0}{1}".Fmt(typeName, suffix.ToUpper());


QueueNames<TestFilter>.In.Print(); // SITE.TestFilter.INQ
```

Note the same configuration also needs to applied on the client so the same MQ names gets used.

### Configuring ServiceStack with AppSettings

ServiceStack is a code-first framework which means all configuration is done in code, but has a [rich and versatile configuration model](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AppSettings) where you can get the behavior your after by reading App Settings in `AppHost.Configure()`:

```
QueueNames.SetQueuePrefix(AppSettings.Get("Tier","dev"));
```

Where if `Tier` doesn't exist in your Web.config (e.g. in Unit Tests) it will use **dev** otherwise will use the value in your appSettings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Tier" value="qa1" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: @Stephen also uses the same Queue Name strategy.

Comment: Just to confirm, even if we're just using Redis for Cache and Session this is the correct way?

Comment: @Stephen It's ok as this only changes MQ Queue names so only affects Redis MQ not the Redis Cache Client.

Comment: Changed my question to clarify the usage of our RabbitMQ message broker and Redis distributed cache. Both are being used simultaneously, but have different roles.

Comment: @Stephen There's no global namespace prefix that applies to all keys in Redis. If you want to use the same redis instance you can [specify to use a different database](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-connection-strings), e.g. `?db=2` on the connection string.